# Sort and insert in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I've got a problem in sorting. I have 2 functions. The first one insert a number into a sorted  list and the second one takes in an unsorted list, named unsorted, creates a new list, and repeatedly calls the first one until the new list is a sorted version of the unsorted input. Then return the sorted list.

My understanding is the very first new list is an empty list, which is kind of "sorted", and insert every element into it one by one. But my code somehow doesn't work. The first function passed the test, but the second one did not. Here's my code:

```
void insertInOrder(list<int>& sorted, int number)
{
    if (sorted.empty())
        {sorted.push_back(number);
    else
    {
        for(list<int>::iterator I = sorted.begin();I!= sorted.end();I++)
        {
            if (*I <=number) 
            {
                sorted.insert((++I),number);// since I increases another time here
                --I;//decrease once back
                return;
            }
            else
            {   
                sorted.insert(I,number);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

std::list<int> reorder(std::list<int>& unsorted)
{
    std::list<int> ordered;
    for (list<int>::iterator J = unsorted.begin(); J!=unsorted.end(); J++)
    {
        insertInOrder(ordered, *J);
    }

    return ordered;
}
```

Comment: Do you *have* to write the sorting yourself? You can't use e.g. [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: it is a homework, so...

Comment: Your insertion sort will only insert a new item at either index 0 or index 1, since no matter the result of the comparison you insert it on the first loop iteration.

Comment: Look at the loop in `insertInOrder`, no matter the condition you always return from the function. So the loop will not even finish one iteration.

Comment: Yes you are right! but if I did not return I will have it insert many times. so maybe I need to use another algorithm?

Comment: Another question: I dont know why but my compiler says (I+1) is a mismatch (and it gives me a crazy long error message). So why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want is that if the value to insert is less than or equal to the current node, then do nothing and continue the loop, else insert and return. This can of course be written as: If the value to insert is larger than the current node in the list, insert it after the current node and exit loop.

So

```
if (number > *I)
{
    sorted.insert(++I, number);  // Insert after current node
    break;                         // Exit loop
}
```

Comment: I dont know why but my compiler says (I+1) is a mismatch (and it gives me a crazy long error message). So why is that?

Comment: @user3275943 Sorry, my fault. I forgot that the iterator used by `std::list` is not a [random access iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), but a [bidirectional iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) which doesn't have that operator. Updated my code.

Comment: If the I is in a for loop and "++I" will be executed after every loop, should I do "--I" after the ++I? I mean, will the extra ++I affect the value of I?THx

Comment: @user3275943 Since you exit the loop if the condition is true, there's no need to do anything like that